# Continuity at $(0,0)$ of $f(x,y)=\frac{x^3+y^3}{x-y}, \; \;(x,y)\neq(0,0)$, otherwise $0$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, continuity, limits-without-lhopital

$f(x,y)=\frac{x^3+y^3}{x-y}, \; \;(x,y)\neq(0,0)$, otherwise $0$

If I use $x=r\cos(t), \; y=r\sin(t)$ & $r\to 0$, I get the limit equal to $0$.
Is this sufficient to prove that the limit of the function is $0$ and that it is continuous?

Basically, I want to know that, if I apply the polar coordinates and if I get a finite constant limit, say $k$ (such a limit will not depend on $t$), then can I claim that the limit of the functions is equal to $k$?     **-------- (1)**

According to my understanding, we are allowing $t$ to vary anywhere between $0 $ to $2\pi$ while taking the limit of $r$ to $0$. So this must mean that we are covering all possible tracks/paths in reaching the point $(0,0)$. Does this interpretation make any sense?

EDIT:-
Ok I realise polar coordinates don't work since

$\lim_{r\to 0} \frac{r^3(\cos^3(t)+\sin^3(t))}{r(\cos(t)-sin(t))} = \lim_{r\to 0}\frac{r^2(\cos^3(t)+\sin^3(t))}{(\cos(t)-sin(t))}$ will give problem when $t=\frac\pi4$

But can I still get the answer to $(1)$?

Comment: What is $f(1,1)$ ??????

Comment: @Fred I need to check only at $(0,0)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't understand how you were able to get the limit $0$ with polar coordinates. The function $f$ has *no* limit at $(0,0)$. Just note that$$(\forall n\in\mathbb{N}):f\left(\frac1n+\frac1{n^3},\frac1n\right)=2+\frac{3}{n^2}+\frac{3}{n^4}+\frac{1}{n^6}.$$

Comment: Can you check my edit please

Comment: Hello José, what led you to choose $x=\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n^3}$ in the input to $f$? Was it so that the denominator does not vanish, or is there another analytical reason?

Comment: I started with the points of the form $\left(\frac1n,\frac1n\right)$, at which $f$ is undefined. And then I added a little somthing to the first coordinate. Actually, at first I tried to add $\frac1{n^2}$, but that didn't work. But adding $\frac1{n^3}$ worked.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Hello Jose, thank you for your response.